# ORMLite (Android) - Removing UUID dashes before persist

Tags: android, uuid, ormlite

I'm starting to use ORMLite in my Android Application that uses UUID as Primary Key in almost every table.

I've made it so I can Import and Export data to my Server Application and ensure there is no duplication.

The problem is: I wrote the code on server-side to save the UUID **without dashes** because it could save some space. (Now I see it was not a big deal, but change it would be a lot time-consuming).

Reading the [ORMLite doc](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_2.html#UUID), I've found this:

> The java.util.UUID class persisted as a VARCHAR type. It saves it as the uuid.toString() and used the UUID.fromString(String) method to convert it back again. You can also mark a UUID field as being generated-id in which case whenever it is inserted, java.util.UUID.randomUUID() is called and set on the field. See section Fields With generatedId.

toString method return UUID with dashes, and I cannot extend UUID because it's final.

I need to, somehow, override UUID.toString() or the pre-save and post-query method of ORMLite to do this:

```
public static String getStringUUID(UUID valor) {
    if (valor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return valor.toString().replaceAll("-", "");
}

public static UUID getValorUUID(String valor) {
    if (valor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return UUID.fromString(valor.replaceFirst("([0-9a-fA-F]{8})([0-9a-fA-F]{4})([0-9a-fA-F]{4})([0-9a-fA-F]{4})([0-9a-fA-F]+)", "$1-$2-$3-$4-$5"));
}
```

How can I could make this possible?

PS: I'm using SQLite and the column type is blob. The server database is Mysql and the column type is binary(16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to, somehow, override UUID.toString() or the pre-save and post-query method of ORMLite to do this:

The proper way to do this (if you can't modify your data) is to use a [custom-persister](http://ormlite.com/docs/custom-persister).  You could easily extend the [UuidType](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/field/types/UuidType.java) and change the `sqlArgToJava(...)` and `javaToSqlArg(...)` method to add and remove the dashes as necessary.

Then you would do something like:

```
@DatabaseField(persisterClass = MyUuidPersister.class)
private UUID uuid;
```

Your persister class would be this:

```
public MyUuidPersister extends UuidType {
    ...
}
```